# Une expression adroite pour « parler une langue mal »

Tags: expressions

Je sais qu’en français on peut dire « Il parle comme une vache espagnole », mais son utilisation semble se borner au français, et l’expression est un peu longue. Vous dites, si je ne me trompe pas, « mon français est rouillé » pour exprimer qu’on le parlait assez bien autrefois, mais que ça fait un bail qu’on l’a plus pratiqué et que sa connaissance s’est un peu perdue. Je dirais même que « rouillé » peut être apposé à toute habileté qui requiert l'emploi du cerveau, pas vrai ?

En néerlandais on un dit parfois « Ce garçon parle français d’houilles ». Il ressort de cette tournure que « ce garçon » parle mal français, mais le français peut également être remplacé par *anglais, allemand* où je ne sais quelle langue. Cependant, la tournure est toujours reliée aux langues.

J’essaie de trouver une traduction satisfaisante. J’espère que ceux qui maîtrisent le français peuvent m’y aider.

Comment: Il y a bien le verbe familier _baragouiner_.

Comment: C’est de [cet Houilles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houilles) qu’il s’agit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J'ai plusieurs solutions

- Parler/savoir dire trois mots [de/en français]
- Baragouiner [en français] (ou avec son voisin du dessus, *baragouiner trois mots de français*.)
- Parler un [français] de contrebande
- Parler [français] comme une vache espagnole (qui s'applique bien à d'autres langues)

Comment: On peut certes « baragouiner en français », mais dans ce cas-ci, je pense qu’il faut privilégier l’emploi transitif :  « baragouiner *le* français ».

Comment: Ah ? Curieux, je ne dirais pas du tout ça comme ça.

Comment: Je serais ravi de voir qu'e quelqu' un enleve les fautes dans mon ecrit.

Comment: [Le TLF B.1.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baragouiner) ; [l’Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/baragouiner)

Comment: non, il s'agit des charbons. Cet adage remonte au debut de la vingieme siecle, et designe l' argot des debardeurs hollandais qui essaient de parler avec les mariniers anglais qui emporaient des charbons par navire.